# How to check the given path is a directory or file in vbscript?

Tags: regex, vbscript

I want to check the path given by user is a directory or a file in vbscript. Is there any regular expression or the other ways I can do this ? Any help would be great.

Comment: Couldn't a directory contain a "." and couldn't a file not have an extension?

Comment: Directory can have "." in its name.

Comment: Then RegEx alone cannot solve your problem. What is your end goal here? We need more info.

Comment: My function is checking folder exist or not. I want to catch the exception when the given path by user is a file and write it into log.

Comment: Try to open it as a folder; if it's not a folder, then it's a file?

Answer (score 5):

```
Function GetFSElementType( ByVal path )
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
        path = .GetAbsolutePathName( path )
        Select Case True
            Case .FileExists(path)   : GetFSElementType = 1
            Case .FolderExists(path) : GetFSElementType = 2
            Case Else                : GetFSElementType = 0
        End Select
    End With
End Function

Function IsFile( path )
    IsFile = ( GetFSElementType(path) = 1 )
End Function

Function IsFolder( path )
    IsFolder = (GetFSElementType(path) = 2 )
End Function

Function FSExists( path )
    FSExists = (GetFSElementType(path) <> 0)
End Function

WScript.Echo CStr( IsFile("c:\") )
WScript.Echo CStr( IsFolder("c:\") )
WScript.Echo CStr( FSExists("c:\") )
```

Answer (score 3):

Add this function to your code and use it, feel free to change sAns to some public Const.

```
Function IsFileOrFolder(sInputText)
    Dim sAns, oFSO
    sAns = "No such a File or Folder!"
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If oFSO.FileExists(sInputText) Then sAns = "FILE: " & sInputText
    If oFSO.FolderExists(sInputText) Then sAns = "FOLDER: " & sInputText
    Set oFSO = Nothing
    IsFileOrFolder = sAns
End Function
```